# cast generic as class and return instance of it

Tags: typescript

I want to get a class as generic, create an instance and return it.

My code is:

```
class Test {
    test1 : string;
}

function do_stuff<T>(arg1, arg2,...) {
    x : any = cast<T>();
    // now we save the class details to later associate it with the other params
}

function cast<T>() : T {
    return new T();      
}
```

Test class is an example, I can get all kinds of classes.

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: it seems the example at the bottom of this page is what you are after: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

While there is an answer in the comments to the question above, the example on the linked page leaves out possible arguments to the generic class's constructor.

Here is a more complete example:

```
function cast<T>(t: new (...args) => T, ...args): T {
  return new t(...args);
}

console.log(cast(Date, 1558736768637));
console.log(cast(Object));
console.log(cast(Number, 55));
console.log(cast(Array, 10, 20, 30, 40));
```

Comment: If there are no overloaded constructors, this: `function cast<T, P extends any[]>(t: new (...args: P) => T, ...args: P): T` is a more typesafe way to handle constructor parameters